# Hide comments column in WordPress backend

Tags: comments, cms

Is there a way to hide the comments column in the backend? When you look at the pages, there's a comments column even though I've disabled them.

I made WordPress into a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) and it may cause some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter("manage_edit-page_columns", "my_page_edit_columns");

function my_page_edit_columns($columns){
  unset($columns['comments']);

  return $columns;
}
```

If you need it for posts instead of pages, use `manage_edit-post_columns` instead. The same goes for any post type, really, as `manage_edit-{post_type}_columns`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this via a plugin or something. I know should we turn the comments back on in the future it will cause an issue doing it via code.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure there's a plugin out there for this specifically. Perhaps you can make your own containing this code? See http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-create-a-functionality-plugin for a good walkthrough.

Comment: Haha, think that may be a bit beyond me!!

Comment: @Rob You can do it! Give the walkthrough a shot. It's really not that bad to take it back out of the theme's functions.php file later on if comments are turned back on, if you just want to try it out. Just be aware that if it's in functions.php, if you change themes or it gets upgraded you will probably lose the functionality. Think of this as a great way to expand your skills :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to ensure that the comments column is removed from all *Post* types and not just *Pages*, use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'comments_array', 'wpse_19986_existing_comments', 10, 2 );
function wpse_19986_existing_comments( $comments ) {
    $comments = array();
    return $comments;
}
```

You can also look into the [Disable Blogging plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-blogging/) which extensively disables the comment functionality among other blog-related features that are needed when using WordPress as a static CMS.